# C - unsigned char in a struct

Tags: c, struct, unsigned-char

Can someone please explain to me the reason I get different results in the output?

I have defined a list using list nodes:

```
typedef struct list_node
    {
        unsigned char letter;
        struct list_node *next;
    } ListNode;

typedef struct list
    {
        ListNode *head; 
    } List;
```

and these functions for a newlist, and for getData:

```
List* newList(unsigned char a) {
    List* new_list = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
    ListNode s1 = { a, NULL };
    ListNode* s2 = &s1;
    new_list->head = s2;

    return new_list;
}

unsigned char getData(List *list){
    ListNode *tmp = list->head;
    ListNode d = *tmp;

    return d.letter;
}
```

but, when I try to test it and print the unsigned char with my getData function, I get a strange result:

```
unsigned char b = 'b';
List* check = newList(b);
unsigned char lettercheck = getData(check);
printf("%u\n",lettercheck);
```

This prints out the value 204,
but when I use  `printf("%u\n", b);`
it prints 98, as it should of course.

I even tried defining the listnode itself like this:

```
List* check = newList(b);
ListNode* d = check->head;
ListNode e = *d;
printf("%u\n", e.letter );
```

which basically just mimics what my function does, and then it prints 
98.

Can somebody please explain this to me? I've been puzzled for quite some time.

Comment: You need to explicitly allocate an instance of ListNode. The one you create in newList (s1) is allocated on the stack and gone just when your function returns. That means: upon the return is executed s2 and thus new_list->head become invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

```
ListNode s1 = { a, NULL };
```

is a local variable, it exists within the stack frame of the `newList()` function, and when the function returns it no longer exists, but yet you have a pointer to it in your struct.

Try this

```
ListNode *s1 = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
if (s1 == NULL)
    handleThisErrorAndDoNotContinuePlease();
s1->letter = a;
s1->next   = NULL;

new_list->head = s1;
```

Some tips:

1. Check for `malloc` return value against `NULL`
2. Don't cast the result of `malloc` it's not needed.
3. Don't forget to call `free()` whenever you finish using the `malloc`ed pointers.

Comment: thanks! it worked! so i need to allocate memory for structs inside a struct as well?

Comment: Yes if you need to access it via a pointer, and in this case you do.